# Exception Azure AD B2C Setting Custom Attribute With GraphServiceClient

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

Following directions from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-user-flow

[image]

I am able to create and get users fine:

```
// This works!
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                    $"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta",
                    AuthenticationProvider);
var user = await graphClient.Users[userId].Request().GetAsync();

if (user.AdditionalData == null)
    user.AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
user.AdditionalData[$"extension_xxxxxxx_Apps] = "TestValue";
// this does not work!
result = await graphClient.Users[user.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(msGraphUser);
```

For xxxxxxx I tried both the Client ID and Object Id from the b2c-extensions-app in my tenant.

Exception

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: Request_BadRequest
> Message: The following extension properties are not available: extension_xxxxxxx_Apps.

How can I set a custom attribute from GraphServiceClient?

Answer (score 5):

Try creating a "new" user rather getting the existing one. When you call `UpdateAsync`, B2C will only set the properties that you provide (it won't overwrite the other props with `null`).  This may or may not help, but the thing is, we're doing the same thing you do above except with a "new" User, and it works for us.

```cs
User b2cUser = await this.GetOurUser(userId);
var additionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
additionalData["extension_id-of-extensions-app-here_Foo"] = "Ice Cream Cone";
var updatedB2cUser = new User
{
    AdditionalData = additionalData
};

await this.GraphServiceClient.Users[b2cUser.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(updatedB2cUser);
```

In practice, we include additional props such as `Identities`, because we use B2C as an identity provider...so the above is some pared-down code from our B2C wrapper showing just the "custom property" part.

***Update***
Actually, you may just need to remove the hyphens from your extension-app ID and double-check which one you're using.

[image]

Comment: thanks actually after I created a new user with it, it is working to update an existing user... go figure...